# Get current user from login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have no problem getting the currently-logged-in user on any other page, but for the Login and Register page, all I get is null.

I've made sure to set the `GetUserByName(User.Identity.Name)` after the login/registration is successful, and of course placed before the redirect action, but the name (or anything for that matter) will not show.

```
case SignInStatus.Success:

                Checker checker = new Checker
                {
                    User = timeRepo.GetUserByName(User.Identity.Name)
                };

                if (model.WantCheckIn == true)
                {
                    //timeRepo.GetUserByName(User.Identity.Name);
                    checker.CheckIn = DateTime.Now;
                    timeRepo.TimeCheck(checker);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", checker);
                }
```

I don't know if I can have the `checker` variable in a redirect action, but it doesn't work either way (no error, just doesn't work) so I don't really know what else to do. I can't-do a `return View(checker)` since it's supposed to redirect you to Home/Index, and that wouldn't work since the `GetUserByName(User.Identity.Name)` doesn't get a value anyway.

This works great for my own controllers where I need the user, but I guess I have to do it another way to get it from the login page.
I *could* make a "hidden" redirect page that does it, but that seems awfully lazy on my part.

All I could find on Google and SO was to get the current user AFTER the login process, which I already can do. It's not really necessary to get a registration date or be able to check in on login, but it would be nice.

Comment: How can you get a user name when the user hasn't logged in yet? This is the case for the Login and Register pages

Comment: It's after the user has logged in that I want it to get the information.
I placed a breakpoint on the Switch case and the "Success" case did indeed give me the user (name, password, ID, everything).
What I want to know is how I can get that info and use it for my check-in / registration dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should review this function 
`User.Identity.Name` have value or not ?

And if User has Authenticated success ,we can get user by using

```
This.User
```

If your controller inherit class `Controller`

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` doesn't have value in this case, that's my question since the user *should* be logged in by now (after the "success" case, all there is is to redirect the user to the main page)

Where would I put `This.User`?

Comment: If user has logged success you can use `this.user` anyway